# How to incorporate a GUI into a C code written in KDevelop?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, qt5, kdevelop

Longtime reader, but this is my first time ever posting. I will try to keep this concise and to the point.  I'm brand new to linux and GUI's so i hope this is the correct forum for posting this:

I have written a navigation program (in C) which takes GPS data via a serial port and displays various navigation info with respect to some destination coordinates.  I have it set to display to console currently and i would like to create a GUI that displays this information (and takes a destination input).  I've been using this video series as a foundation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SsYseswQ-4&list=PL5E68C8BA78B5DA6C&index=11

However my versions of Kdevelop (4.7) and QT Creator (not sure but its at least version 5) are not consistent with that vid series and I have exhausted the information i can obtain from it.  I need to create a GUI that i can link with my already written C code and i have had a difficult time getting started on QT Creator (i've read all the manuals and QT design tutorials they provided).  If anyone can direct me to a better method or to a more current guide for using QT creator simply as a platform for exporting a .ui file and linking it with other software i would appreciate it.

If my question was too vague, or not "code" related enough i apologize.  If i can provide any info to improve this question let me know.

EDIT: Qt version is 5.3.2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is well written, but it is [probably off-topic because you're really asking for a tutorial/advice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). SO is more geared to help you once you've tried _something_, and have a more specific question and some code to show (as you seemed to have realized). Keep trying! Build some of the Qt sample code, and post a more specific question if you run into problems.

Comment: Note: This question is not KDevelop related at all, both KDevelop and QtCreator are just IDEs -- you seek advice how to use Qt, as a GUI toolkit, instead. Better update your title & tags.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you linked is a little too old, you can try 
[this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkjaiDsiM-Q&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZiBcTr5urECberTITj7gjA) that is from last year.

Once you can write a QT/C++ GUI, you can always use your C code in it, also if this is generally deprecated given the problems that can arise.
This approach can be a good starting point so you have a running software and after that you can rewrite your C code in C++ (which, in my opinion, is the best thing you should do)